# How to force all street names to show up on a map when using the google api to build an android app

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I am currently building an android app in android studio and am unable to make street names appear for the region of interest (Stepanakert, Nagorno-Karabakh). I believe that street names exist for this region because they are visible on google maps. I know that I have enabled street names in the java code because they are visible in other regions from within my app. The relevent code that I am using is as follows:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mMap;
LatLng stepanakert = new LatLng(39.8177000, 46.7528000);
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(stepanakert,13));
mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
}
}
```

I am in need of help making the street names appear in Stepanakert. My hypothesis is that there is a disconnect between the map info that I am using from the google map api thing in the app and the information which is actually available to the public through google maps. See the below pictures to further understand my problem:

[image: Stepanakert Within my App (no street names visible)]

[[image: Stepanakert Within Google Maps (street names visible)]

Answer (score 0):

You can style your map with `GoogleMap.setMapStyle()` method and change how to show street name's and other attributes by passing **JSON** style file to it:

```
    try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        boolean success = mMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.style_json));

        if (!success) {
            Log.e("MapsActivityRaw", "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("MapsActivityRaw", "Can't find style.", e);
    }
```

You can create your custom style and get json file from the following Link https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Put the json file in **`/res/raw/style_json.json`**

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but, unfortunately, it has not fixed the problem; street names remain invisible in Stepanakert.